# How to read object from url in JS

Tags: javascript, object, url

I have a Javascript SPA I'm working on (no framework) and currently I am writing the properties object to the URL using

```
window.location.hash = pagename + "/" + JSON.stringify(properties);
```

So now the URL looks like:

```
domain.co.uk/#creator/{"fitting":"","color":"red"}
```

Is there any way that I can use JS to read the object in the URL bar on page load (to repopulate the local object) for the purposes of users sending the URL to each other and bookmarking the page?

I've looked up some solutions online but all seem to involve reading parameters in the traditional sense (e.g. name=jack not name: "Jack")

Thanks very much!

Comment: `location.hash` will get you access to the `#creator/{"fitting":"","color":"red"}` part of the URL – and then all you need to do is split it (simple regular expression), and then decode the JSON …

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way :

```
var object = JSON.parse(location.hash.substr(location.hash.indexOf('{')));
```